# ggtern breaks ggplot2 and produces plots without axis labels etc

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I noticed that, since *ggplot2* released their new version (3.3.0), I can no longer use the package *ggtern*, as it completely breaks all my plots produced with *ggplot2*.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame("x" = c(1,2), "y" = c(2,1))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
```

This produces a normal plot:
[image: normal ggplot]

However, when i load *ggtern*, I get the following:

```
library(ggtern)
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
```

No axes etc.:
[image: ggplot after loading ggtern]

It also stays this way when i detach *ggtern*, so I have to restart R to produce normal plots again.

A workaround is to downgrade *ggplot2* to an older version (i.e. version 3.2.1), however, this comes with other downsides.

Is there another workaround where I can use the **current *ggplot2* Version and *ggtern***?

Comment: I think ggtern is incompatible with the most recent ggplot2 version, there was discussion on ggplot2's github about this: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3561#issuecomment-5986825191

Comment: thank you for the link! hopefully a solution can be found. seems that in the meantime, I will have to stick to ggplot2 version 3.2.1

Comment: hey I am on ggtern_3.1.0  ggplot2_3.2.1, don't see this problem

Comment: That's right, since ggtern overrides ggplot2 functions and ggplot2 has updated it's code, ggtern now breaks ggplot2. ggtern doesn't cause any problems with the older ggplot version.

Comment: Also seeing this. Opened an issue at the project bitbucket:  https://bitbucket.org/nicholasehamilton/ggtern/issues/13/ggtern-breaks-ggplots-plot

Comment: In Rstudio having gtern::gtern in a script breaks ggplot, even before running the line. How is that possible? Does Rstudio automatically pre-load packages?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work-around I found. I save my plot into variable `p`. Then I call `ggplot2:::plot.ggplot(p)`. That at least makes axis text show up for me.