# Error with geom_interpolate_tern() and stat_interpolate_tern() in ggtern

Tags: r, ggtern

I am trying to generate response surface plots for ternary mixtures using ggtern. Using either `geom_interpolate_tern()` or `stat_interpolate_tern()` I receive the following error:

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in stat_interpolate_tern():
Number of x coordinates must match number of columns in density matrix.
```

Initially I was using my own data, but I have taken a step back and I am using the Feldspar data provided with the package. When I directly use the example from the documentation:

```
data(Feldspar)
ggtern(Feldspar,aes(Ab,An,Or,value=T.C)) + 
stat_interpolate_tern(geom="polygon",
                     formula=value~x+y,
                     method=lm,n=100,
                     breaks=seq(0,1000,by=100),
                     aes(fill=..level..),expand=1) +
                     geom_point()
```

I receive the same error and generate the following plot:
[Feldspar Ternary Plot with `geom_point()` and `stat_interpolate_tern()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIvpK.jpg)
But I should generate: [Image from documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5u4I.png)

As you can see, the `geom_point()` layer displays correctly, and I have tested out a number of the other ggtern geoms which all function properly. I am using R 4.0.0 and ggtern 3.3.0. Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like ggtern is not compatible with the newest ggplot version. We've seen problems in the axis labels (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989586/ggtern-breaks-ggplot2-and-produces-plots-without-axis-labels-etc). Maybe this interpolation is related

Comment: Opened an issue in the project Bitbucket (https://bitbucket.org/nicholasehamilton/ggtern/issues/15/geom_interpolate_tern-not-working). But I'm not sure how frequent the package is maintained